# Ubuntu Touch Screen OS

Tags: updates

Can Ubuntu work on tactile touch screens? What is the minimum specification required to achieve this? Which version of Ubuntu is required? Will it work on a Zenis POS Series POS-3000 Version 1.1 provided by Fametech Inc TYSSO April 2010. CPU support; intel Atom N270 1.6ghz, 512KB cache, 533MN FSB.
currently runs old WINDOWS.

Comment: Sorry! 533MB FSB

Answer (score 0):

You really want to contact the manufacturer directly for clarification:

http://www.tysso.com/

There's also little to be said if you do not provide the exact model of display. In very general terms, **capacitive** displays work mostly out-of-the-box in the newest (14.04+) versions of Ubuntu while **resistive** displays usually require you to install additional drivers which might or might not be available for Ubuntu. And this is precisely what you should ask your provider given that you don't want to research yourself or just go and try to install Ubuntu 14.04 or 15.10.

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Apologies. I thought the following information did state the model of display: "Zenis POS Series POS-3000 Version 1.1 provided by Fametech Inc TYSSO April 2010. CPU support; intel Atom N270 1.6ghz, 512KB cache, 533MN FSB. currently runs old version of XP called POS 2009 which is build in to terminal."

Comment: As far as I can see, this states the model of the device, but not of the touchscreen itself. POS-Manufacturers usually use displays from other manufacturers (eGalax, Elo, 3M...). Maybe you can extract more information on the touchscreen and/or used driver by accessing the System Information in Windows? Anyway, asking the manufacturer of the device should the quickest way to know if the device is compatible straight away with Ubuntu or not.